# Why is this component switching from controlled to uncontrolled? - React

Tags: reactjs, redux

Here is my stateless react component:

```
export default ({acresMin, update}) => (
    <div>
        <input
            onChange={(e) => update({'acresMin': e.target.value})}
            placeholder="10"
            type="text"
            value={acresMin}/>
    </div>
)
```

When I change the value in the `input`, I get this `warning`:

`Warning: StatelessComponent is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`

I am updating with an `onChange` and saving the value in the `store` which is being populated through the `props`.

What do I not understand about this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Uncontrolled input* does not refer to your component directly, but to the input field that is defined in your component.

React differentiates between [controlled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [uncontrolled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components):

> An `<input>` without a value property is an uncontrolled component

**Is your `acresMin` property `undefined` when you first render the component?** This would cause the input to be renderd as an uncontrolled one at first, but as a controlled one later once the property is set.